# Unexpected `&&` Syntax Error

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I'm not sure why this code is causing this syntax error but the error I'm getting is : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in /srv/m/a-1.php on line 12`

And the code:

```
if ($valid != FALSE) && (!isset($_COOKIE['set'])) {
```

What needs to be fixed?

Comment: `if ($valid !== FALSE && !isset($_COOKIE['set']) )`, I would use strict comparison in `$valid` and remove the bracket after `FALSE`

Answer (score 3):

Missing "("

```
if ( ($valid != FALSE) && (!isset($_COOKIE['set'])) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `(` and final `)`.

It should read

```
    if (($valid != FALSE) && (!isset($_COOKIE['set']))) {
```